# Python: Find and remove strings from the text

Tags: python, regex, string, text

I`am trying to sort out a big text file that contain users and information about them. The task is to clear this text from specific user, delete user and all information about him that goes below.

File example:

```
User=Andy
Age:12
Weigh:45
...
reg.info:12
User=Sam
...
```

The problem that it is solid .csv  file,I a don`t know proceed it.

Here is my code how to find line with specific user and it`s line number:

```
user = []
linenum = 0
pattern = re.compile("Andy", re.IGNORECASE)  # Compile a case-insensitive regex
with open ('UserDB.csv', 'rt') as myfile:    
    for line in myfile:
        linenum += 1
        if pattern.search(line) != None:      # If a match is found 
            user.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
for err in user:                            # Iterate over the list of tuples
    print("Line " + str(err[0]) + ": " + err[1])
```

Output:

```
Line 622909: "User=Andy"
```

Now how can I delete all the lines below this user not yet the information about next user begin?

Comment: does the initial file have to be updated?

Comment: The data doesn't look like a `csv` file. `csv` stands for *Comma-separated values*, but it doesn't contain any commas. That's strange.

Comment: @Brian nowadays anything can serve as a separator in a .csv, including newlines.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, in the way of removing specific users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly know how your CSV file looks like but provided that the text looks as you wrote, you can use the following regex to select all of Andy's information

```
(?<=User=Andy\n)(.+\n)+(?=User)
```

`(?<=User=Andy\n)` is a positive look behind making sure that we selected the right user (Andy in this case)
`(.+\n)+` selects all user's information, and more specifically selects every character with new line at the end, multiple times (all the lines)
`(?=User)` is a positive lookahead making sure that we select information only till the next user

The only thing is that you'd have to delete the line with `User=Andy` manually yourself.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, I just need to apply it to each line in the file?

Comment: Rather to the entire document

Comment: I have some troubles how to use it...
```pattern = re.compile((?<=User=Andy\n)(.+\n)+(?=User))```

Comment: What is the problem exactly

Comment: How to apply it to the entire doc =P

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you open another file for writing your new values too i.e the names without the parts you want deleted. Once you've gone through all the entries you can delete your old file and keep the new one.

```
with open('UserDB.csv', 'rt') as infile:
   with open('new_UserDB.csv', 'w') as outfile:
      for line in infile:
          list.append(processing(line))
          outfile.write(processing(line))
```

Comment: Umm.. I don't think you need to create new file. You can use a+ for reading and writing both together! Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Ali Hamdan Yes, it is a way, but again, how to copy without unwanted parts?

Comment: @干猕猴桃 you can only write the line which satisfies your condition `pattern.search(line)` into the `outfile` by putting the write in that block.

Answer (score 0):

`ax.csv` looks like ... as u mentioned above & if the line maintains in that order

User=Andy
    Age:12
    Weigh:45
    ...
    reg.info:12
    User=Sam
    Age:10
    Weigh:65
    ...
    reg.info:11
    User=Chris
    Age:20
    Weigh:55
    ...
    ...

```
import re

users = {}
p = []

with open('ax.csv', 'r') as f:
    lines = re.findall(r'User=.*', f.read())
    for l in lines:
        patt = re.findall(r'=(.*)', l)
        p += patt
    f.close()

users = dict([(k, v) for k,v in enumerate(p)])
print('\nUser list ...\n', users)

output:
-------
User list ...  
{0: 'Andy', 1: 'Sam', 2: 'Chris', 3: 'William'}
```

So are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. As I see it's create a user list, it's quite helpful but I need to remove specific user, for example Sam, and all info connected to him

Comment: here user list is a dict() for that `users`, which keeps only the names of the user & rest of the part is removed... from that `ax.csv` file. now if u want to add other info(s) into that u can do so, or if if you want to remove a specific user. then find that key like `users.has_key(key_name)` and remove it.

Comment: Ok, got it. But for some reason I receive empty user list
`
User list ...
 {}
`

Comment: @干猕猴桃: make sure, your file_stream is working... & lines of that file should follow this hierarchy. otherwise, regex may not work so u'll get empty lines/patterns may b... but what u can do is debug it line-by-line by printing or using `pdb.set_trace()`